# wxWidgets Application Release Issue

Tags: deployment, release, wxwidgets

I have developed window base application in Visual Studio using wxWidgets. Application working fine. But when I make the release of application and test on another system where no visual studio installed, the application give me the error

> Not Install property Reinstalling may
>   fix your problem

Release of my application only works where Visual Studio Installed. I have also tested after installing .NET Framework, but the same error. Please guide me so that I can successfully deployed my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include all the required libraries for your application.

There are two sets: the wxWidgets libraries and the C runtime libraries.

There are two ways to include these libraries, depending on how you built your application - by using static libraries or by using DLLS.

The easiest way to do your first release is to use static libraries.  This means that all the reuired library code is included in your executable by the linker.  This makes the executable rather large, but simplifies the release.

To link the C run time libraries statically: In Visual Studio select Project | Properties | C/C++ | Code Generation | Runtime Library | Multi-Threaded /MT

You will also have to build the wxWidgets libraries using the static runtime libraries and then specify the static wxWidgets libraries to the linker.

You can see lots of useful information on these subjects [here](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Microsoft_Visual_C++_Guide)